# Expression in Entity Framework?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The Entity Framework does not support the Expression.Invoke operator. You receive the following exception when trying to use it:

"The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Has anyone got a workaround for this missing functionality? I would like to use the PredicateBuilder detailed [here](https://pmkisanbeneficiarylistwb.in/) in an Entity Framework context.